# Can't get loss to decrease on this tensorflow lstm model

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to predict sequences using the LSTM modules of tensorflow, but to no avail. I can't figure out the problem and I was hoping someone could lend me a helpful hand. Here's my code:

First I mostly create synthetic data, and prepare the dataloader

```
x = np.linspace(0,30.,500)
y = x*np.sin(x) + 2*np.sin(5*x)
nb_steps = 20

def load_batch(batch_size = 32): 

    x_b = np.zeros((nb_steps,batch_size,1))
    y_b = np.zeros((nb_steps*batch_size,1))

    inds = np.random.randint(0, 479, (batch_size))
    for i,ind in enumerate(inds): 
        x_b[:,i,0] = x[ind:ind+nb_steps]
        y_b[i*nb_steps:(i+1)*nb_steps,0] = y[ind+1:ind+nb_steps+1]

    return x_b, y_b
```

Some shortcuts

```
adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer
layers = tf.layers
dense = layers.dense
lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell
batch_size = 64
```

Then, comes the part where I create the model

```
with tf.variable_scope('data'): 

    x_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [nb_steps, None, 1], name = 'x') # batch, steps, features 
    y_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, 1], name = 'labels')

with tf.variable_scope('network'): 

    cell = lstm(num_units = 100)
    outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x_p, dtype = tf.float32, time_major = True)


    reshaped_outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1,100])
    projection = dense(reshaped_outputs, 1, activation = None, name = 'projection')
```

Just above is the part I'm the least certain of. I reshape the output of the lstm for each time step and stack them on the first axis (or do I ?). I then send the whole matrix in a linear layer.

```
with tf.variable_scope('training'): 

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(projection - y_p))
    train_lstm = adam(1e-3).minimize(loss)


epochs = 1000
batch_size = 64
f, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    mean_loss = 0. 
    for epoch in range(1,epochs+1): 


        x_b,y_b = load_batch(batch_size)

        batch_loss,_ = sess.run([loss, train_lstm], feed_dict = {x_p:x_b, y_p:y_b})

        mean_loss += batch_loss

        if epoch%100 == 0: 
            print('Epoch: {} | Loss: {:.6f}'.format(epoch, mean_loss/100.))
            mean_loss = 0. 

    while True : 

        x_b, y_b = load_batch(1)
        pred = sess.run(projection, feed_dict = {x_p:x_b}).reshape(-1)

        ax[0].plot(x,y, label= 'Real')
        ax[0].plot(x_b.reshape(-1),y_b.reshape(-1), label= 'Real batch')
        ax[0].plot(x_b.reshape(-1), pred, label = 'Pred')

        ax[1].scatter(x_b.reshape(-1),y_b.reshape(-1), label= 'Real')
        ax[1].scatter(x_b.reshape(-1), pred, label = 'Pred')

        for a in ax: a.legend()

        plt.pause(0.1)
        input()

        for a in ax: 
            a.clear()
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each LSTM cell produces 100 outputs, so after you execute tf.nn.dynamic_rnn you need to flatten that output. I'd rather use

```
reshaped_outputs = tf.layers.Flatten()(outputs)
```

after this line:

```
 outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x_p, dtype = tf.float32, time_major = True)
```

instead of this line:

```
reshaped_outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1,100])
```

Hope it helps :)

EDIT: I didn't notice that you used time_major = True. I have changed your code a bit, with time_major = False, because it's simpler to use.

I assume that you want to predict nb_steps outputs.

code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,30.,500)
y = x*np.sin(x) + 2*np.sin(5*x)
nb_steps = 20

def load_batch(batch_size = 32):

    x_b = np.zeros((batch_size, nb_steps))
    y_b = np.zeros((batch_size, nb_steps))

    inds = np.random.randint(0, 479, (batch_size))
    for i,ind in enumerate(inds):
        x_b[i] = x[ind:ind+nb_steps]
        y_b[i] = y[ind+1:ind+nb_steps+1]

    return x_b, y_b

adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer
layers = tf.layers
dense = layers.dense
lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell
batch_size = 64

with tf.variable_scope('data'):
    x_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, nb_steps], name = 'x')
    x_rnn = tf.expand_dims(x_p, 2) # batch, steps, features
    y_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, nb_steps], name = 'labels')

with tf.variable_scope('network'):
    cell = lstm(num_units = 100)
    outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x_rnn, dtype = tf.float32, time_major = False)
    reshaped_outputs = tf.layers.Flatten()(outputs)
    projection = dense(reshaped_outputs, nb_steps, activation = None, name = 'projection')

with tf.variable_scope('training'):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(projection - y_p))
    train_lstm = adam(1e-3).minimize(loss)


epochs = 1000
batch_size = 64
f, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    mean_loss = 0.
    for epoch in range(1,epochs+1):

        x_b,y_b = load_batch(batch_size)

        batch_loss,_ = sess.run([loss, train_lstm], feed_dict = {x_p:x_b, y_p:y_b})

        mean_loss += batch_loss

        if epoch%100 == 0:
            print('Epoch: {} | Loss: {:.6f}'.format(epoch, mean_loss/100.))
            mean_loss = 0.
```

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for helping, but actually, this raises an error concerning the input dimension to the last layer being None

Comment: File "time_serie_tf.py", line 41, in <module>
    projection = dense(reshaped_outputs, 1, name = 'projection')
 raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! (: I indeed used `time_major = True` as I was accustomed to PyTorch. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Most definitely (: